# Questions about Jrpg NPC events (Unity C#)

Tags: unity, c#, rpg, json

So, I'm trying to wrap my head around something. I've got my basic quest system up and running for my rpg style game.

Right now I'm taking a look at NPC events and triggers that as I see it have two distinct styles

1. The classic floor panel trigger that rpg maker uses or
2. have a listener class for quest active / event active

My questions are thusly what's the best way to go about activating the event and what's a good way to define the event? Like set movement patterns etc would it be feasible in json? Or should I use scriptable objects?

Comment: These are viable options which might or might not be good solutions depending on the rest of your game architecture, what kind of "quests" you have and what those "npc events" are supposed to do. There are usually several ways to do something in Unity and there rarely are "right" and "wrong" ways to do something. Have you tried any of these yet? Have you noticed any situations which are handled poorly by your approach?

Comment: @Philipp My games based on the use of a Messaging Queue though this is a single player RPG while I haven't tried any of the ways quite yet I was really trying to understand the Pro's and Con's of each before making a step forward